# softlayer_api gem OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using softlayer_api gem but when i called any method like "getOpenTickets" after

creating SoftLayer::Service object i get this exception:

**OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed):**

my code that is executed in dashboard controller is:

def index

```
begin

  account_service = SoftLayer::Service.new("SoftLayer_Account",

                                           :username => "sl221577473gghg717a",

                                           :api_key =>
```

"25f38a342079c07f4336543a0fccc54ee8755cb92b53cd78d0hdufh77734747hreghghed4aa1d9961b85")

```
  account = account_service.getOpenTickets

rescue Exception => exception

  puts "Unable to retrieve account information: #{exception}"

end
```

end

i also require related libraries as well

require 'rubygems'

require 'softlayer_api'

require 'pp'

require 'openssl'

any opinion will be greatly appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Reason is that your SSL verification is failed.So please find where softlayer_api gem is

installed and go to service.rb and find the line below.

```
https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE  if $DEBUG
```

and replace it with

```
https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Start server and check!